# Changing the Toolbar Text Without Changing the Title

Tags: javascript, html, css

Does anyone know how to change the browser toolbar without changing the title? I am trying to get the site to bookmark and read to screen readers with the first letter. Currently the first letter is presented using:

```
<link rel="icon" href="img/U.png">
```

But if I then put the U in the title, it shows up along with the png.
I tried the window.toolbar property, but it only has a read-only visible attribute. It is also possible to change the color using:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#db5945">
```

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android

But none of these methods seem to allow one to change the appearance independently of the title.
For reference, here is the site with the title that needs to be different from what is on the toolbar:
http://u-eat.org/

Thank you,

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is not possible. The title in the DOM is the same as the one in the tab.